# Why am I receiving "object does not support this property method"?

Tags: excel, vba

I have information in a whole lot of worksheets in workbook Wb1 and this information is always in range F11:F500 I want to transfer this information into one sheet in workbook wb in column A. See code below. I receive the error
at this line rng2.Paste

```
Option Explicit
Sub NameRisk()

    ' Copy and paste

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim rng2 As Range

    Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks("COMBINED ADD.xls")
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks("NameRiskXtract.xlsm")

    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")


    For Each ws1 In wb1.Sheets
        Set rng = Range("F11:F500")
        For Each c In rng
            If c.Value <> "" Then
                c.Copy
                With ws
                    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    Set rng2 = ws.Range("A" & lastrow)
                    rng2.Paste
                End With
            End If
        Next c
    Next ws1
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [`Range.PasteSpecial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial), but if you only need the values, `rng2.Value = c.Value` is much better than copying and pasting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Range("F11:F500")` should have a parent worksheet; I'm guessing it is `ws1`. You may be cancelling the Copy operation. Better to  Copy with a destination.

```
...
For Each ws1 In wb1.Sheets
    Set rng = ws1.Range("F11:F500")
    For Each c In rng
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            c.Copy destination:=ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next c
Next ws
...
```

Comment: Yes.  `Range("F11:F500")` refers to the ActiveSheet. You are looping through the worksheets in wb1 so I'm guessing that you want `ws1.Range("F11:F500")`.

Comment: Congrats on hitting 100K!

Comment: Thanks @MathieuGuindon!

Answer (score 1):

You are still in your `with` statement. try:

```
For Each ws1 In wb1.Sheets
    Set rng = Range("F11:F500")
    For Each c In rng
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            c.Copy
            With ws
                lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                Set rng2 = .Range("A" & lastrow) " <--- removed ws
                rng2.Paste
            End With
        End If
    Next c
Next ws1
```

You may also want to avoid copy/paste entirely and use this snippet instead:

```
For Each ws1 In wb1.Sheets
    For Each c In ws1.Range("F11:F500")
        If c.Value <> "" Then ws.Range("A" & ws.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1).value = c.value
    Next c
Next ws1
```

Comment: I think `v.value` should be `c.value`. I don't see any With ... End With to provide a parent worksheet to Range("F11:F500").

Comment: You're right. the "c" key is just too close to the "v" on this keyboard... The parent worksheet is `ws1` which is set in the loop, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: There's no `With ws1`, just `For Each ws1 In wb1.Sheets`. It should be `Set rng = ws1.Range("F11:F500")`.

Comment: Ah! I see wherre the confusion comes from. Edited my answer for clarity. Thanks!